# Generate title from database and show related post

Tags: php

I have a DB name askadoc , where people can ask about their problem. I want to show all question(or you can say the titles) together in a page. And then when user click on a question, the question will show in a different page with it's comments/details. To do this i have tried the below code and its working perfectly. but how can i do it without using button ?

```
<?php

       $comment = "SELECT * FROM `askadoc`  ";
       $result = mysqli_query($conn, $comment);
       $question = "";
       $id="";
       if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $id = $row["id"];
            $question = $row["question"];
            ?>
            <form action="post.php" method="post">
                <?php
                       echo $id;
                       echo "<input type='hidden' name  = 'id'  value = ".$id.">"; 
                       echo "<button>".$question."</button>";
                       echo "<br>";                   
                ?>
            </form>
            <?php  
          }
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: why not just anchor tag or link?and pass in the question id.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need form this. You can user anchor like this.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $id = $row["id"];
        $question = $row["question"];
        ?>
        <a href='post.php/<?php echo $id ?>' target="_blank"><?php echo $question ?></a>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Now when you click this anchor, you get question id inside post.php, so easily you can display a particular question comments.

Comment: Thanks for your kind comment,  It's working but it does not shows the comments along with it. what i did i take the question id from the database. keep it hidden and when button(title button) is pressed (as a submit) another query shows the comments . in your code it shows only the titles how can show the commets as well ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use anchor tag then pass the question id to post.php

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $id = $row["id"];
            $question = $row["question"];
            ?>
                <?php

                       echo "<a href='post.php?question_id=".$id."' target='_blank'>".$question."</a>";
                       echo "<br>";                   
                ?>
            <?php  
          }
}
```

Then to get the value of `question_id` use `$_GET['question_id'];`

```
$questionId = $_GET['question_id']
```

and its better to check if question_id does exist.

```
$questionID = isset($_GET['question_id'])? $_GET['question_id'] : '';

if(!empty($questionID)){
  //Use $questionID here to query some data from database
}
```